# If $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous and $|f(x)|\leq a+b|x|^\alpha$, then the induced map $f:L^p\to L^{p/\alpha}$ is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, continuity, lp-spaces

Let $\Omega$ be a *bounded* open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.
If $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$ is continuous and $|f(x)|\leq a+b|x|^\alpha$, is the map $F:L^p(\Omega)\to L^{p/\alpha}(\Omega)$ given by $F(u) =f\circ u$ continuous when $p>\alpha$?

I know that that $F$ is well defined since
$$\|F(u)\|_{p/\alpha}\leq \|a+b|u|^\alpha\|_{p/\alpha}\leq  a|\Omega|^{\alpha/p}+b\|u^\alpha\|_{p/\alpha}=  a|\Omega|^{\alpha/p}+b\|u\|_{p}^{\alpha}<\infty.$$

However, I don't know how to invoke the continuity of $f$ in the proof of continuity of $F$, if this is even possible to begin with.

EDIT: fixed a few typos with the exponents.

Comment: Let $u_n \to  u$ in $L^{p}$. Show that $f\circ u_n \to  f\circ u$ in $L^{p/\alpha}$ using DCT.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Oh nice! I should've thought of using sequential continuity since $L^p$ spaces are metrizable! Can you please write this hint in an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: For the hint by @Kavi, the following might be useful: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/261842/looking-for-a-reference-for-a-version-of-the-the-reverse-lebesgue-dominated-con .

Comment: Thanks! I think I know how to solve it. But it would be great if someone writes an answer just for the sake of completeness.

Comment: Also, can the continuity of $f$ be relaxed? What alternate conditions on $f$ can give continuity of $F$?

Comment: You can also write an answer yourself. Continuity is essential, as you can see by considering constant functions.